# about auto increment field in triggers

Tags: trigger

i want to auto increment on when a new record is created using triggers. i have customer object and customer_serial_No field whenever a customer is created customer_Serial_No is incremented

Comment: Why not use an autonumber field?

Comment: I agree that an autonumber field is the tool for the job described here. If that's not an option, you should [edit your question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/152435/edit) to include details on what you've tried so far. As is, this question sounds like a "do it for me" request, which don't tend to garner many answers. I'd recommend reading through [the help center on asking questions](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/asking), specifically [how to ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested try to use Auto number field to auto-increment as this can be taken care of by the system. If you still need to have trigger use the customer_serial_no to increment it each time based on the highest value, make sure to create a custom index for this field as it will lead to SOQL error when the data size increases.

Regards,
Bharath